# ¿Por qué mi apk android pesa tanto?

Tags: android-studio, app, apk

El peso de mi proyecto comprimido es de 419kb (exportado como zip) la app solo tiene línea de códigos, y uso las librerías: Volley, itext, y cloudmessaging como extras!, nada más.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

solo tiene líneas de código, nada de imágenes, primero el `app_debug.apk` pesa unos 2 megas, luego con un poco más de código, no mucho se fue a 8mb, luego lo conecte con firebase para cloud messaging, y ahí el `app_debug.apk` se me fue a 27 megas, número bastante incómodo para estar bajándolo por la play store, ya que solo es líneas de texto, nada pesado, he verificado que no tengo archivos pesados en el proyecto, también agregue las reglas de proguard minifyEnabled   true y   shrinkResources true.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

solo de agregar líneas de texto el tamaño fue aumentando, y actualmente este es el tamaño actual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea por dónde empezar? ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: 419Kb no es "pesado"

Comment: Las librerías por lo general suelen pesar entre 100 y 150 kb, estás usando 3, vamos 300Kb, además sumando el peso de todos los ortos archivos obtenemos un número de kb "elevado" similar al final (446 KB)

Comment: Exacto, 419kb, no es pesado, pero ese no es el problema, sino que mi APK final, es de 28 megas, cuando no tengo nada mas que lineas de codigo.

Answer (score 0):

El proyecto comprimido en .zip que generas desde Android Studio tiene un peso diferente a el archivo .apk generado,  **la razón es que al compilar se descargan dependencias que hace que el archivo .apk crezca**, en este caso comentas que tienes dependencias como Volley, iText, y Google Cloud Messaging las cuales usas en tu proyecto.

Por ejemplo yo tengo un proyecto el cual totalmente pesa 10MB pero al generar mi .APK se obtienen aproximadamente 30MB.

Comment: gracias por responder, tenia las 3 dependencias, pesaba 8 megas, y de un dia para el otro, con solo escribir o cambiar código, me refiero a pocas lineas, el APK final se fue a 28 megas.. una locura